# DataContext accessible from IMultiValueConverter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have WPF application and I need to bind two arguments (no matter what they are) to calculate the value (checkbox checked or not). So I have to use `IMultiValueConverter` and that's fine.

But is there a way, to give this converter access to `DataContext` (ViewModel) of a window I am binding to?

Basically I have some checkboxes in treeview, i need to pass to converter content (text) of theese checkboxes and its parent's header. Then in converter I need to process that text and find out if it's present  in some collection I have in my ViewModel (`DataContext`). I know that I cannot use ConverterParameter, because it doesn't support binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another `Binding` to your `MultiBinding` that binds to the view model, e.g.:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter}">
    <Binding Path="Property1" />
    <Binding Path="Property2" />
    <Binding Path="DataContext" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}" />
</MultiBinding>
```

Comment: Thank you. Such a simple solution, should have come up with it myself :)